# call different custom cell in each UISegmentController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have one UIViewController with UITableView inside,above table I have UISegmentControl, when I press on segment control I want to load a UItableCustomeCell, would you please help me in this implementation, I don't know how should I add them in cellForRowAtIndexPath, Since I have 3 different Custom cell

Here is the code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
 *)indexPath

{

if (indexPath.row == self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == Test1) {
    MytestsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MytestsCell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[MyBooksCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
reuseIdentifier:@"MytestsCell"];
    }

    return cell;
}
else if (indexPath.row == self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == tests) {
    testCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"testCell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[TestsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
 reuseIdentifier:@"testsCell"];
    }

    return cell;
}
break;
case 1:
 if (indexPath.row == self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == PTest) {
    PTestsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PTestsCell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[PTestsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
reuseIdentifier:@"PTestsCell"];
    }

    return cell;
}
break;

}
```

I don't want to have 3 of them in one table, each custom cell is for one segment control

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One alternative I can think of is to switch the table views data source. But I would not recommend that. You could define a delegate of your data source and ask it for the table view cell for a selected segmented control. But this just moves the problem. I would stick to your approach.

Answer (score 0):

So...here is what I would do. Starting with iOS6, you no longer need to check if your cell is nil after dequeuing from the tableview if you use

```
- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You are guaranteed to get a cell back as long as the identifier exists. Also, it doesn't look like you need to do any additional configuration so something like this should work:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];
     return [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Edit: I forgot to add, that in order to use this, use numbers that correspond to the segments as the identifier for each cell.

Comment: thanks for reply, what should I write in this method ? - (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: You don't need to do anything, it is a method that was added to the UITableView class in iOS 6. If you look at the answer, you can see that we are using the new dequeue method to get a cell from the tableview using the identifier string and then returning it.